# Problems Alphabetically Sorting an Array of Strings

Tags: c++, debugging

Before you light the torches, I am trying to teach myself C++. I feel like I've got a good grasp of it, but I gotta dive in to reach the bottom if you know what I mean. I am trying to debug a simple program I am trying to make to teach myself. This programs goal is to alphabetically sort an array of strings in print each one out. I probably should use pointers in here when passing the arrays to my length() function but I haven't gotten that far yet. There are so many errors that I am not sure where the error actually is. Please tell me it's something like a missing semi-colon. I am pretty sure that the if (itemsToSort[j] < firstInAZOrder) line won't work but again, I am trying to learn the language and I have to start somewhere.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stringarray.h"

void output (int sortedItems) {
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        std::cout << sortedItems[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    std::string itemsToSort[] = {
        'bob', 'john', 'tyler', 'anthony', 'luke', 'eric'
    };
    std::string sortedItems[length(itemsToSort)];
    string firstInAZOrder;

    for (int i = 0; i < length(itemsToSort); i++) {
        firstInAZOrder = itemsToSort[i];

        for (int j = i + 1; j < length(itemsToSort); j++) {
            if (itemsToSort[j] < firstInAZOrder) {
                firstInAZOrder = itemsToSort[j];
            }
        }

        sortedItems[i] = firstInAZOrder;
    }

    output(sortedItems);
    return 0;
}
```

stringarray.cpp:

```
int length (std::string array) {
    return sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
}
```

stringarray.h:

```
int length (std::string array);
```

Here is the list of errors and warning Xcode gave me:

- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:12:3: warning: multi-character character constant -
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:12:18: warning: character constant too long for its type
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:12:27: warning: character constant too long for its type
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp: In function 'void output(int)':
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:6: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char* const*)':
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:13: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:13: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc = std::allocator]'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:13: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:13: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc = std::allocator]'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:13: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:13: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc = std::allocator]'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:13: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:13: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc = std::allocator]'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:13: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:13: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc = std::allocator]'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:13: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:13: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc = std::allocator]'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:14: error: conversion from 'std::string*' to non-scalar type 'std::string' requested
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:15: error: 'string' was not declared in this scope
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:15: error: expected `;' before 'firstInAZOrder'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:17: error: conversion from 'std::string*' to non-scalar type 'std::string' requested
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:18: error: 'firstInAZOrder' was not declared in this scope
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:20: error: conversion from 'std::string*' to non-scalar type 'std::string' requested
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:26: error: 'sortedItems' was not declared in this scope
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/main.cpp:29: error: 'sortedItems' was not declared in this scope
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/stringarray.cpp:10: error: 'string' is not a member of 'std'
- /Users/Tyler/Desktop/sort/stringarray.cpp:10: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all:

```
std::string itemsToSort[] = {
    'bob', 'john', 'tyler', 'anthony', 'luke', 'eric'
};
```

The quote character (') can only be used on a single character.
Use double-quotes (") for this:

```
std::string itemsToSort[] = {
    "bob", "john", "tyler", "anthony", "luke", "eric"
};
```

Next:

```
void output (int sortedItems) {
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        std::cout << sortedItems[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This function takes a single integer, and that's not what you want at all.  Assuming you want to learn how to use pointers, you could try something like:

```
void output (int* intArray, int arraySize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
        std::cout << intArray[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This function takes a pointer to some number of integers in memory, and the number that are there.  This solves the next problem of knowing when your `for` loop should terminate.

In real code you would use something like `std::vector` in place of `int*`.

Answer (score 4):

A string constant should be in double quotes, not single quotes:

```
"bob"
```

Single quotes are for character constants.

Then,

```
int length (std::string array) {
    return sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
}
```

should take an array as input, but even then won't work and can't be fixed except by making it a macro (which is a sure way to get you banned from the C++ experts' guild for a decade) or by making `length` a template function, which may be a bit advanced. Use `std::vector` instead, it has a `size` method for this.

Finally,

```
void output (int sortedItems) {
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        std::cout << sortedItems[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

doesn't really take an `int`, does it? A stop condition in the loop would also be nice, to prevent the proverbial dragons flying out your nose.

Comment: It's easy enough to find the size of an array: `template<typename T, int N> int length(const T (&)[N]) {return N;}`

Comment: And it's even easier to find the length of a `std::string`: `s.length()`.

Comment: @Mike: you're right, fixed that, thanks. (Your `int` should be a `size_t`, though.) @Roland: The OP wants the length of a `string` array.

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the errors one at a time -

The first one is because you need double quotes (") not single quotes (')

The second one - try int *sortedItems

Just keep redcuing them one at a time, after it compiles, the debugger will be your friend